# Stacks Project proof that gluing locally ringed spaces which happen to be schemes gives a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, ringed-spaces

I'm currently reading the [Stacks Project section on gluing schemes](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01JA). I can understand the proof of [Lemma 01JB](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01JB), but it is hard for me to understand the proof of [Lemma 01JC](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01JC). By constructions of the locally ring space $(X, \mathscr O_X)$ in [Lemma 01JB](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01JB), we know that we can look at the restrictions $\mathscr O_X|_{U_i}$ which are isomorphic to $\mathscr O_{U_i}=(\varphi_i)_*\mathscr O_i$. Then clearly if the $(U_i, \mathscr O_{U_i})$ are schemes the restrictions are then schemes. But why are the locally ringed spaces $(U_i, \mathscr O_{U_i})$ and $(X_i, \mathscr O_i)$ isomorphic? Is it true that because the inverse of $\varphi_i$ is an open immersion (a homomorphism to the entire $X_i$ and the canonical map $\varphi_i^{-1}(\varphi_i)_*\mathscr O_i\to\mathscr O_i$ is an isomorphism), by [Lemma 01HH](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01HH) on [open immersions](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01HD), there is an isomorphism of locally ringed spaces from $(U_i, \mathscr O_{U_i})$ to $(X_i,\mathscr O_i)$?

Comment: Some tips on referencing the Stacks Project: the numbers of results may occasionally change as portions of the text are edited, but the *tags* are guaranteed never to change. Therefore it's preferable to use the tags when citing results. I've made the upgrades for you this time.

Comment: @KReiser thanks for the modification and the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement of lemma 01JB involves open subspaces $U_i$ of $X$, and isomorphisms $X_i \rightarrow U_i$. This means that $U_i$ is isomorphic as a locally ringed space to $X_i$.

To show this, you can check that the inclusion $X_i \rightarrow X$ is an open immersion of locally ringed spaces giving an isomorphism $X_i \sim U_i$. It's an open embedding on the level of topological spaces, and since $O_X$ is constructed by gluing $O_{X_i}$, the structure sheaves agree.

Therefore, if all $X_i$'s are schemes, then $X$ can be covered by schemes, so $X$ is  a scheme.